# Get default value '-' from case statement when sum value is zero

Tags: sql-server, sum, case

I Have a table like below,

```
client id   order q     order date
----------- ----------- ----------
1           0           2016-02-01
1           0           2016-05-03
```

When the sum([order q]) = 0 I want the result is '-', If it returns value greater than zero,I Want the result.

I tried the following query, but it returns zero only.

```
select case when sum([order q]) = 0 THEN '-' else sum([order q]) END 
from t1
```

Help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are intending to `GROUP BY` the client id value:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SUM([order q]) = 0 THEN '-'
            ELSE CAST(SUM([order q]) AS VARCHAR)
       END
FROM t1
GROUP BY [client id]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should convert the sum() to Varchar. Try like this,

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (
    clientid INT
    ,orderq INT
    ,orderdate DATE
    )

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES (
    1
    ,0
    ,'2016-02-01'
    )
    ,(
    1
    ,0
    ,'2016-05-03'
    )

SELECT CASE 
        WHEN sum(orderq) > 0
            THEN convert(VARCHAR(10), sum(orderq))
        ELSE '-'
        END as orderq
FROM @t
```

Answer (score 1):

Since '-' is a character and sum([order q]) will be of numeric data type you cannot use the syntax as you mentioned in the question, you have to convert both into similar data types. Try this query

```
SELECT CASE ISNULL(SUM([order q]), 0)
           WHEN 0
           THEN CONVERT( CHAR(1), '-')
           ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), SUM([order q]))
       END
FROM t1;
```

Answer (score 1):

As your **datatype** for order column is **int** so it **won't work** . The datatype is always set to a **column datatype** which you are using in **aggregate function**. As you are **mentioning here '-'** it **internally** converts it in to -0 and as 0 cant be in **negative** it **displays you 0**

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE 
AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),SUM([order q])) as c1 from t
)
SELECT 
  CASE c1 
    WHEN '0' THEN '-' 
    ELSE c1 
  END as c2 
from CTE
```